# Wordpress admin-ajax.php error 400 bad request

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

hello  im doing save for later feature in my website
but i get admin-ajax bad request when i click the button

functions.php

```
function zumra_scripts() { 
    wp_register_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/remove-product.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list', 'sfl_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )) );
    if ( is_page('savelist') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zumra_scripts' );
```

save-for-later.php

```
  <?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    $user =         $_POST['user'];
    $post_id =      $_POST['post_id'];
    $response =     $_POST['saveForLater'];
    $response .= '<a href="'. site_url("/savelist") .'">'. __( 'Browse Savelist', 'zumra' ) .'</a>';

    add_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $post_id);

    echo $response;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_product_from_list', 'remove_product_from_list' );
function remove_product_from_list() {
    $user =     intval( $_POST['user'] );
    $product =  intval( $_POST['product'] );

    delete_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $product);

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_move_to_cart', 'move_to_cart' );
function move_to_cart() {
    $user =     intval( $_POST['user'] );
    $product =  intval( $_POST['product'] );

    delete_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $product);

    // do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product );
    // wc_add_to_cart_message( $product );

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

save-for-later.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ajax-form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'saveForLater': sfl_ajax.response,
            'user':         sfl_ajax.user,
            'post_id':      sfl_ajax.post_id,
            'product_id':   sfl_ajax.user_product,
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(sfl_ajax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('.save-for-later').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

i don't know what im doing wrong 
i get error admin-ajax.php 400 every time i click add to save for later button

Comment: 400 error usually coming when the URL is not correct. Can you check in the console that which URL is going ?

Comment: no the url is correct http://localhost/zumra/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and when i open it i get 0

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code.  I am assuming that you have include this file in the functions.php of your active theme.

Or

You can add this code in your functionctions.php directly.

As is described in the Wordpress AJAX documentation, you have two different hooks - wp_ajax_(action), and wp_ajax_nopriv_(action). The difference between these is:

- wp_ajax_(action): This is fired if the ajax call is made from inside
  the admin panel.
- wp_ajax_nopriv_(action): This is fired if the ajax
  call is made from the front end of the website.

  ```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
  add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action","remove_product_from_list");
  function my_action() {
    $user =         $_POST['user'];
    $post_id =      $_POST['post_id'];
    $response =     $_POST['saveForLater'];
    $response .= '<a href="'. site_url("/savelist") .'">'. __( 'Browse Savelist', 'zumra' ) .'</a>';

    add_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $post_id);

    echo $response;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_product_from_list', 'remove_product_from_list' );
  add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_product_from_list","remove_product_from_list");
  function remove_product_from_list() {
      $user =     intval( $_POST['user'] );
      $product =  intval( $_POST['product'] );

      delete_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $product);

      wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
  }

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_move_to_cart', 'move_to_cart' );
  add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_move_to_cart","GetEditForm");
  function move_to_cart() {
      $user =     intval( $_POST['user'] );
      $product =  intval( $_POST['product'] );

      delete_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $product);

      // do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product );
      // wc_add_to_cart_message( $product );

      wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
  }
  ```

Comment: i earased the code in save-for-later.php and added this code still get same error

Comment: there is one mistake from my side total you are having three ajax call while I have given you two. Just add nopriv in your ajax of third one.

Comment: Please check my answer Again.

Comment: same error jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 POST http://localhost/zumra/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: What is the permalink type in wordpress?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what do you mean by permalink type
this is the permalink of the page that have the save for later button
http://localhost/project/product/coconut-milk/

Comment: Your url is different, As of now you are saying this is ( http://localhost/project/product/coconut-milk/ ) your url and previously you have said you are having ajax url is this ( http://localhost/zumra/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php ).

You ajax url must be same. for example if you project is runnign on http://localhost/project/ then your ajax url must be http://localhost/project/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: the urls are the same i just retyped it as project for seo reasons :DD
but they are the same im sure all are zumra not project i made that up